# MySQL using LIKE operator on result of CASE statement and reformatted DATETIME-column

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL query where I also need to take a user search-input as a parameter. I was originally going to use the FULLTEXT index to efficiently search all the columns in the table to provide the best search results, but due to limitations in the FULLTEXT index I had to opt for just the LIKE operator. The reason for this is I also need the user to be able to search in the ID column of the table and the DATETIME column, and to my understanding, the FULLTEXT index can only search in columns having a sort of text or character field. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Anyways it works all fine, but in the SELECT part of the query I have 1 CASE function and 2 DATE_FORMAT functions, which the user needs to be able to search in. This is the query I am working with:

```
SELECT i.itemID, d.dictionaryID, m.modelName, b.brandName, c.categoryName, p1.fname, p1.lname, p2.fname, p2.lname,
date_format(u.startDato, "%W %e. %M - %H:%i") "dateAdded", date_format(u.returDato, "%W %e. %M - %H:%i") "datePlannedReturn",
CASE
    WHEN u.accoutPermission = 1 THEN "Moderator"
    WHEN u.accoutPermission = 2 THEN "Administrator"
    ELSE "User"
END AS permission
FROM item i
INNER JOIN model m ON m.modelID = i.modelID
INNER JOIN dictionaryItem d ON d.dictionaryID = i.dictionaryID
INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandID = d.brandID
INNER JOIN category c ON c.categoryID = d.categoryID
INNER JOIN person1 p1 ON p1.personID = i.personID
INNER JOIN userAccount u ON u.accountID = d.accountID
INNER JOIN person2 p2 ON p2.personID = d.personID
WHERE u.accountID = x AND i.state = 1 AND (i.itemID LIKE "%search term%" OR c.brandName LIKE "%search term%" OR c.categoryName LIKE "%search term%" OR p1.fname LIKE "%search term%" OR p1.lname LIKE "%search term%"
OR p2.fname LIKE "%search term%" OR p2.lname LIKE "%search term%" OR dateAdded LIKE "%search term%" OR datePlannedReturn LIKE "%search term%"
OR permission LIKE "%search term%")
```

The problem here is that the LIKE operator on the "permission" column is only searching for the value of the u.accountPermission and not the result of the CASE-function. The same goes for the "dateAdded" and "datePlannedReturn" columns, it compares the search term to the original DATETIME--format and not the reformated date-format. Does anyone know why this happens?

Also, is there any better way to search in all of the returned columns, or do I have to spesify each one individually?

EDIT:

I managed to fix both my issues by using HAVING instead of WHERE for the search-operation and used LOCATE('search term', CONCAT_WS(column1, column2, column3, ...)). This ended up being much cleaner, faster and reliable. Thanks for the help!

Here is the updated Query:

```
SELECT i.itemID, d.dictionaryID, m.modelName, b.brandName, c.categoryName, p1.fname, p1.lname, p2.fname, p2.lname,
date_format(u.startDato, "%W %e. %M - %H:%i") "dateAdded", date_format(u.returDato, "%W %e. %M - %H:%i") "datePlannedReturn",
CASE
    WHEN u.accoutPermission = 1 THEN "Moderator"
    WHEN u.accoutPermission = 2 THEN "Administrator"
    ELSE "User"
END AS permission
FROM item i
INNER JOIN model m ON m.modelID = i.modelID
INNER JOIN dictionaryItem d ON d.dictionaryID = i.dictionaryID
INNER JOIN brand b ON b.brandID = d.brandID
INNER JOIN category c ON c.categoryID = d.categoryID
INNER JOIN person1 p1 ON p1.personID = i.personID
INNER JOIN userAccount u ON u.accountID = d.accountID
INNER JOIN person2 p2 ON p2.personID = d.personID
WHERE b.brukerID = x AND u.state = 1
HAVING LOCATE('search term', CONCAT_WS(i.itemID, b.brandname, c.categoryName, p1.fname, p1.lname, p2.fname, p2.lname, dateAdded, datePlannedReturn, permission))
```

Comment: Filtering by the output expression is not allowed in WHERE but is allowed in HAVING (even when there is not GROUP BY clause - this is MySQL extension). Or use the copy of the expression instead of the output column name.

Comment: `.. WHERE column1 LIKE "%search term%" OR column2 LIKE "%search term%" OR ..` can be replaced with `.. WHERE LOCATE('search term', CONCAT_WS('?', column1, column2, ..) ..`. Concatenation + one searching is faster. `'?'` is a char or a substring which is absent in `search term` - for example, you may use `CHAR(9)` or even `CHAR(0)`.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using such a shotgun approach.  Instead, craft the search query based on what the user enters.  ("If it quacks like a duck, assume it is a duck".)

Pseudo app code:

```
if it looks like an account number
    SELECT id WHERE acct_num = ?
else if numeric input
    SELECT id WHERE id = ?
else if it looks like dddd-dd-dd,
    SELECT id WHERE date_col = ?
else if ...
    ...
else if it is long enough to be used in fulltext
    SELECT id WHERE MATCH(text1, text2, ...)
               AGAINST ("+$string" IN BOoLEAN MODE)
else
    your current SELECT (but getting only `id`)
```

Then put that as a derived table thus:

```
SELECT lots of columns from lots of tables
    FROM (whichever of the above you picked) AS ids
    JOINs to get other columns
    ORDER BY ...
    LIMIT ...
```

Then declare a FULLTEXT index on just the text columns showing in that MATCH.